# stuck at reading credentials from txt file correctly

Tags: c++

I am stuck at reading credentials from txt file. what am I doing wrong?

I can successfully create new file each time and open it but don't know in what format should I save so I can read it correctly. like should I make separate file for username/email and passcode or one file. should I save username and passcode at same line or next line.

I am a student and just trying to make program in order to learn so please avoid any silly mistake made by me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
bool status;
//system("clear");
int counter = 0;
string new_passcode = "0", confirm_passcode = "0", em, pw, temp2;
char acc_check;
string email, passcode;
string temp;

string temp_email;
//int index = 1;ss
bool login()
{

    //string email, passcode, em, pw;
    ifstream read;
    read.open("credentials.txt", ios::in);
    if (read.is_open())
    {
        while (!read.eof())
        {
            getline(read, temp_email);
            //getline(read, pw);
            cout << temp_email << endl;
            //cout << pw << endl;
        }
        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter your email id" << endl;
            cin >> email;
            cout << "please enter your passcode" << endl;
            cin >> passcode;
            temp = email + passcode;

            if (temp_email == temp && /*pw == passcode &&*/ counter < 3)
            {
                cout << "login successful";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                cout << "Trials left :" << 3 - counter << endl;
            }

        } while (temp_email != temp /*&& pw != passcode)*/ && counter < 3);

        cout << "blocked";
        //return false;
    }
    else
        cout << "unable to open file";
    read.close();
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Login syetem" << endl;
    cout << "Do you already have acc ,press Y/N" << endl;
    cin >> acc_check;
    if (acc_check == 'N' || acc_check == 'n')
    {
        int passcode_loop = 0;
        do
        {

            cout << "Sign Up!" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your email" << endl;
            getline(cin >> ws, email);
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            cout << "Enter your passcode" << endl;
            cin >> new_passcode;

            cout << "confirm your passcode" << endl;
            cin >> confirm_passcode;
            if (new_passcode == confirm_passcode)
            {
                passcode_loop = 1;

                ofstream file_2("credentials.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
                file_2 << email << new_passcode << "\n";
                file_2.close();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Passcode didn't match ,enter password again";
                system("clear");
            }

        } while (passcode_loop == 0);
    }
    else if (acc_check == 'Y' || acc_check == 'y')
    {
        login();
    }
    else
        cout << "invalid answer";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that you're just learning coding -- but still, you should never store plain text passwords. And using text files for something like this isn't really a useful skill anyhow, because in the real world you would typically use a database, or at least something like sqlite

Comment: `while (!read.eof())
        {
            getline(read, temp_email);` should be `while (getline(read, temp_email)) {`

Comment: Choosing the format for your data is a design decision for you to make. Ask yourself why you are considering these options. Weigh the pros and cons for your particular situation, then choose an option. (Then write modular code so you can easily change your approach if you discover a new factor to consider.) *If you have decided upon a format and are having trouble implementing the read, that would be a different question. For trouble reading a format, your [mre] could be much shorter, as you would only need the code that reads the data. Hardcode what is currently user input.)*